# Monodevelop on Xubuntu Missing ASP.NET

Tags: ubuntu, mono

I am running XUbuntu 16.04 and I installed `mono-complete` and `monodevelop`. However when I run Monodevelop, I can't create a web project. It seems like ASP.NET is not installed.

How can I install ASP.NET?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/770299/monodevelop-on-xubuntu-missing-asp-net

I just downgraded to using 14.04, which seems a lot easier.

Comment: This answer is no longer relevant as monodevelop is now installed through the flatpak.